# How can I change the value of a non-HTML attribute within an input field using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have an input box like the following:

```
<input type="text" value="" somethingSpecial="filename.txt" id="myID" class="box">
```

I also have a select list like the following:

```
<select name="type" class="form-select" id="type">
    <option value="keyword" selected="selected" otherValue="filename.txt">Keyword</option>
    <option value="title" otherValue="filename1.txt">Title</option>
    <option value="author" otherValue="filename2.txt">Author</option>
    <option value="subject" otherValue="filename3.txt">Subject</option>
</select>
```

When a user picks an option from this select list, lets say, "Title" for the sake of this example, then I need the "otherValue" to be pulled out of this field, so "filename1.txt" and swapped out for the "somethingSpecial" value in the Input box.

Normally, I would just use a function to access the HTML attribute, like name, id, class, etc... but obviously the ones that I am using are none of the conventional attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do such things, you can use `.attr()`, but the preferred way is to use custom data attributes (their names begin with `data-`) and `.data()` methods to access / change them. They are part of HTML5, but are accessible also in earlier versions in HTML (see John Resig's article: [HTML 5 data- attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)).

```
<input type="text" value="" data-somethingSpecial="filename.txt" id="myID" class="box">
```

and then access it like that:

```
jQuery('#myID').data('somethingSpecial')
```

and change like that:

```
jQuery('#myID').data('somethingSpecial', 'something else')
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$("#myid").attr("otherValue")
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using jquery.data()

you can use the HTML5 syntax in your markup like:

```
<option id="title" value="title" data-otherValue="filename1.txt">Title</option>
```

access in jquery with:

```
$('option#title').data('othervalue')
```

I'm sure you can build on this example and select your options as an array or something.

Comment: I should add that this is supported by all browsers through jquery even old IE6 and different doctypes than HTML5.